# Converting SQL query to Lambda query using best practice

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to transcribe the SQL below to Lambda Expression and wondered how best to me indicate to this conversion.

```
declare @codigoGrupo int
declare @nomeModelo varchar(20)

set @codigoGrupo = 8 -- null
set @nomeModelo = '%segundo%'

select g.dc_nome, m.dc_nome
from hlp.grupo_solicitacao g
     left join hlp.modelo_solicitacao m on g.codigo_grupo_solicitacao = m.codigo_grupo_solicitacao
     where 1=1
     and (g.codigo_grupo_solicitacao = @codigoGrupo or @codigoGrupo is null)
     and (m.dc_nome like @nomeModelo or @nomeModelo is null)
```

Comment: Is this for Linq to Entities ( Entity Framework )?

Comment: It's for linq2sql, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

I really think that it will be strange with lambda expression. It is easier to do it like this and much cleaner:

```
int? codigoGrupo =8;
string nomeModelo="segundo";
var result= (
    from g in grupo_solicitacao
    from m in modelo_solicitacao
         .Where(a=>a.codigo_grupo_solicitacao=g.codigo_grupo_solicitacao)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    where 1==1
    && (g.codigo_grupo_solicitacao==codigoGrupo || !codigoGrupo.HasValue)
    && (m.dc_nome.Contains(nomeModelo) || nomeModelo==null)
    select new{g.dc_nome, m.dc_nome}
);
```

Comment: If you are fine with the answer then you might consider accepting it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
int? codigoGrupo = 8;
string nomeModelo = "segundo"

bool filterCodigoGrupo = codigoGrupo.HasValue;
bool filterNomeModelo = !String.IsNullOrEmpty( filterNomeModelo );

var list = context.grupo_solicitacao
  .Where( o =>
    ( 1 == 1 )
    &&
    ( !filterCodigoGrupo || o.codigo_grupo_solicitacao == codigoGrupo.Value )
    &&
    ( !filterNomeModelo || o.modelo_solicitacao.dc_nome.Contains( nomeModelo ) )
  )
  .Select( o => new { codigo = o.dc_nome, model = o.modelo_solicitacao.dc_nome } )
  .ToList();
```